# どうか〜〜ますように in 「どうか異世界の出来事でありますように」

Tags: translation

I don't know what possible translations are for this sentence:

> どうか異世界の出来事でありますように

also I'm a little confused by どうか and ~ように...

Comment: The first couple of [search results for ように](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB) may already answer the second part of your question. The first part may be answered by the first two [results for どうか](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B).

Comment: Are there any parts of the sentence you *do* understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a form used to express a wish. Like in English "I wish that this will turn out to be a dream", or "I wish you good health".

You convert the plain sentence expressing what you wish into formal language and add 〜ように at the end. For example, if you want to wish somebody to have a great day. You may want to use the sentence:

```
今日【きょう】が最高【さいこう】の一日【いちにち】になる
```

Which means "Today will become the greatest day". To make this into a wish format, you change it into ます form to make it more formal/polite, and add ように:

```
今日【きょう】が最高【さいこう】の一日【いちにち】になりますように。
```

This means "I wish today becomes the greatest day".

Adding どうか at the beginning is a way to emphasize the wish - turning it from just a wish into a fervent wish, so to speak.

The idea is that a wish is much like a prayer - you address the "powers that be" or the gods - and therefore it has to be formal, polite and humble.

So, I think the translation of your sentence is something like "Please make it be a parallel-universe incident". The exact translation depends on context, of course.