# Is there any usage of である outside the literary works?

Tags: dialects, formality

I have heard であります being used in TED talks, as use of である i have heard it in Kotaro but that also in a comical way as Kotaro talks like his favourite Samurai character.

Is there any dialect that still uses this ?

[image: I have found 40469 returns for であります]

Comment: Sometimes I hear it used in relative clauses even outside of literary works

Comment: What is Kotaro? The manga/anime Kotaro Lives Alone, or something else?

Comment: @YusukeMatsubara yes

Comment: https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%80%9C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99 this may help you

Comment: This ありますように is [a way of making a wish](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19082/5010), and it's only natural to use a pompous phrase like あります.

Comment: @Chance Thank you ! So it's used in military

Answer (score 1):

であります is grammatically a form of である, but their usages are very different.

- **In the middle of a sentence**, である is common at the end of a relative clause. This type of である is preferred in formal sentences, but does not sound particularly literary.

  - [Relative clause ending with a noun should be followed by の or である? What is the difference?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36743/5010)
  - [Usage of noun-modifying である](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9929/5010)
- **At the end of a sentence**,

  - である is the default copula in academic manuscripts, Wikipedia articles and the like. だ sounds too blunt in such cases. In novels, である and だ are used interchangeably or arbitrarily according to the writer's preference.
  - であります (the polite version of である) is unusual and sounds rather pompous. It doesn't sound particularly samurai-ish, but people usually only use it in very formal speeches or conferences. If anything, using it a lot will make you sound like a politician or a military man.
  - Of course, its negative version, で(は)ありません, is super-common and used in every kind of polite sentences.